# Software to show Android LogCat

Tags: android, logcat

Is there a lightweight software that can get LogCat logs from my android device and print them on a console-like screen?

By lightweight, I mean a few megabytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view logs with

```
adb shell logcat
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

You can also view logs on your computer:

> To view log output using adb, navigate to your SDK platform-tools/ directory and execute:

```
adb logcat
```

That's about as lightweight as it can get :-)

Comment: Does it work on its own or does it need Android SDK?

Comment: You can take the `adb` executable and use that only (so no it does not need the whole SDK).

Answer (score 1):

**Recommended**: [Punt](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/punt) - cli tool that makes adb logcat better

**Others**:

1. [logger](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger) - Simple, pretty and powerful logger for android.
2. [timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) - A logger with a small, extensible API which provides utility on top of Android's normal Log class.
3. [LoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/ihsanbal/LoggingInterceptor) - An OkHttp interceptor which pretty logs request and response data.
4. [Bugfender](https://github.com/bugfender/BugfenderSDK-android-sample) - Upload your logs and check them online, specially made for mobile
5. [EzyLogger](https://github.com/afiqiqmal/EzyLogger) - Simple Lightweight logger
6. [Logback Android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) - Logback port to Android which provides a highly configurable logging framework for Android apps.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6 are not what he asked for. He wants logs on his computer not inside the app.